# Entity Framework (Database First) Can't Find Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

I have two separate projects, one for data interaction and another for the WebUI.

The web.config in the root of the WebUI project has the following connection string:

```
<add name="MySiteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MySite.csdl|res://*/MySite.ssdl|res://*/MySite.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:**********.database.windows.net,****;initial catalog=MySite;user id=username@**********;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The dbcontext generated by the EDMX (database first) has the following:

```
public partial class MySiteEntities : DbContext
{
    public MySiteEntities()
        : base("name=MySiteEntities")
    {
    }
...
```

When I run the site locally entity framework finds the connection string and successfully connects to the database.

However, when I publish, entity framework cant seem to find the connection string and instead throws a `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you verified that the published application is using the correct config file? In my environment, I have Debug and Released config files, and when I run locally, it's the Debug version but I publish the Released (which changes a few things)

Comment: @Ryan Both my release and debug versions of my config file are the same. I verified this by connecting via FTP and checking the web.config. The web.config has the exact same connection string as posted.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in debugging is to make sure you understand the exception being thrown. According to the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.unintentionalcodefirstexception%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), `UnintentionalCodeFirstException` is:

> The exception that is thrown when a context is generated from the
>   DbContext templates in Database First or Model First mode, and is then
>   used in Code First mode.

That's not terribly helpful, but it does clue you in sort of to what's going on: you generated your context using Database First or Model First, but now for some reason, the context thinks it's supposed to be Code First.

A little searching based on this netted me: [Don’t use Code First by mistake](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/), which does a fair job of explaining possible causes. I suggest you give it a read and see if anything pops for you.

My best guess, since this works locally but not remotely, is that the EDMX mapping that corresponds to your connection string didn't make the jump for whatever reason. If you're using source control, perhaps it didn't get committed. Without this mapping, EF will result to a Code First strategy which will result in this exception.

Comment: As mentioned in the article: "OnModelCreating will never be called when using the Database First approach." I agree that something must be wrong with my EDMX mappings since entity framework seems to be trying to use code first. I have no clue as to what could be wrong with my EDMX but I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the "tcp:" in the value for datasouce, in your connection string.  I don't have that in the config for my azure app, and it works fine.